# how can I skip some iteration of for loop and do others iteration in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a program that all the function is in the for loop. I want to skip some numbers of variable in for to don't do any thing if a condition goes true. for example:

```
 for i=1:a

      for j=1:b
       if counter=101
       %until i<21 do nothing then if i=21 continue the loop and do what I want   
       % until i=23, after that again i goes forward but don't do any thing 
       %until i=44 again do the progress and continue the loop.
       end


       %do what I want 

      end

    end
```

but I can't get the right answer. 
I write it like down:

```
if counter==101
             j=1;
            while (i < a/3+1)
                i=i+1;
                continue
            end
        end
        if counter==201
             j=1;
             while (i < 2*a/3+1)
                 i=i+1;
                 continue
            end
        end
```

In this code, after i=21 do iteration, after that in for loop i goes to the number before 21(for example 3) but i don't want it. 
If anyone has advice, that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please, correct the hierarchy of the code

Answer (score 3):

This condition should be what you are looking for:

```
for i=1:a
      for j=1:b
          if i < 21 || (i >= 23 && i < 44)
              % Skip loop before 21 and between 23 and 43
              continue
          end
          if counter == 101
               % Do stuff
          end
      end

end
```

There is at least an error in your code: `if counter=101` is not a valid comparison, you are assigning the value 101 to counter. You should use `if counter==101`
Also, I do not understand your second block of code at all. A the very least, you use `i` before assigning a value to it and an outer loop is probably missing.

Edit:
That being said, you might want to simply adjust your looping variable:

```
range = [1:20 , 22, 44:a];
for i = range
    % Do stuff
end
```